# How do I batch rename files in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have a folder full of files and they all look like this:

frame_*number*_delay-*number*.gif

I would like to delete the **frame_** and the **_delay** part.

Help please!

Comment: Asked many times... shows no effort to research answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell for that. Open it and navigate to your folder that contains the files you want to rename with `cd`. Then run the next command:

```
cd C:\Path\to\your\folder
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.gif -File | Foreach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.replace("frame_","").replace("_delay","") -WhatIf }
```

`-WhatIf` means this is a dry run. Remove it once you're happy with the shown result to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the software [Renamer](http://www.den4b.com/products/renamer). It's free.

Create a remove rule that contains the text `frame_` and another one that contains `_delay`.

[image: renamer software for windows creating a rule by removing text]

Comment: this doesn't provide a proper answer to the question. See [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/241386)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Megamorf's answer is correct, but it can be improved, here is my two cents.

The commands can be shortened to an one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\to\folder" -Filter "*.gif" -File -Recurse | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name -replace "frame_|_delay") -WhatIf }
```

In the command "C:\path\to\folder" is a placeholder for the actual path, replace the path with the actual path when you run the command;

The `-Recurse` switch specifies the command to process subdirectories as well;

`%` when used with a scriptblock (any commands between `{` and `}`) is an alias to `ForEach-Object`, if not used followed by a scriptblock then it means the modulus operator (i.e. `21 % 6` will return `3`), it is customary to use `%` indicate `ForEach-Object`;

The `-Replace` operator uses regex match, and you don't need to provide the replacement, so you can replace two strings in one step, saves a lot of characters.